# How to make input text type="button" unselected in ie & firefox

Tags: html, text, input

How to make input text type="button" unselected in ie & firefox without js

Comment: Could you explain your question a little more please as it's quite vague.

Comment: In a text field or in the web page?

Comment: Ah. I love the details on that one.

Comment: If we want your text we will get it.  You cannot stop us.  Rest assured, however, that no matter what you think of the text on your webpage nobody really don't think its worthwhile to take it.

Answer (score 0):

Unselected? Do you mean disabled?

`<input type="button" value="Hello" disabled="true">`

[image]

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Unselected could mean...

"unselect" as in once it's highlighted - to lose focus. (this is definitely JS)
"disabled" as in the button isn't usable - (above example)

Comment: I mean..when I push the button and move mouse the text on it selected. I need no js.

Comment: I didn't know you could select text in a `<input type="button">`. I can't reproduce it on IE8 Chrome / FF latest. I don't know the answer. Good luck!